# How to open a file which is already open in exclusive mode?

Tags: c++, windows, file

I want to access a file which is already opened with exclusive access by some other process (not under my control). I know that the I/O manager will not grant my request, as some other process is holding the lock (with exclusive access).

Is there any way by which I can bypass the checks (such as file opened in exclusive mode) made by I/O manager and get access to file even if its opened in exclusive mode (CreateFile() will fail)?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be careful trying this out. Your changes may interfere with the other process.

Comment: Does that not defeat the purpose of the other process having the file open in **exclusive** mode?

Comment: Yeah, the other process is dumb(it's windows itself), I just want to read one tiny thing, it will take hardly take a few clocks.

Comment: it's a huge file, and the part I want to read never changes.

Comment: @lalli: But still, the other process has the file open **exclusively**. It doesn't matter if you think your access will change much, or take long. Unless you can persuade the other process to release the lock, I'd say (without any knowledge of the Windows API) that there **should not** be any way to do this. (Are you by any chance trying to poke around in the swap file?)

Comment: @DevSolar: I totally agree with your point, there should not be **a way** to do this. I'm asking, is there **a hack** to do this?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to read the swap file. Actually, just trying to find it's LBA locations.

Comment: @lalli: If there is, I'd expect Microsoft to disable it with a hotfix ASAP. From a security standpoint, being able to peek around in swapped-out data (unless you're Administrator, and perhaps not even then) is close to a worst-case scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup api (volume shadow copy) may help you to obtain a copy of that file.

Comment: In conjunction with the respective privileges. Good call. +1.